# Wordpress, Gutenberg Templates how to add Lables between blocks?

Tags: wordpress, templates, editor, block, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm forcing a block template for the editor view of a specific custom post type using basically this example as a guide:

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/#locking

```
function myplugin_register_template() {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'post' );
    $post_type_object->template = array(
        array( 'core/paragraph', array(
            'placeholder' => 'Add Description...',
        ) ),
    );
    $post_type_object->template_lock = 'all';
}
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_register_template' );
```

I was able to set multiple input fields and change their default attributes like their placeholder or content.

What I would love is the ability to add a label in the editor above the input field.
The only solution I could find was creating a static block with static text.
Awful.
I would need to create a block for each label.

I would love a way to set its content from the placeholder or content attribute from the above template definition code but, for the life of me, I can't find any documentation on how to go about it.

so the questions are:

1. is there an easier way to set a static label above each field in a template that I'm missing?
2. is there a way to implement a label block that takes a content attribute from there?

Comment: seems that support for gutemberg is puzzling for everyone, that makes me feel better

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a 3 step approach you can add an extra attribute/s and insert custom content to existing blocks without creating a new block. After the additional attribute is added, you can then set the default value in your custom post template which is then displayed in the Editor, eg:

**Step 1:** Use [Register Block Type Filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#blocks-registerblocktype) to assign a new `label` attribute to the existing  `"core/paragraph"` block:

plugin.js:

```
function addLabelAttribute(settings, name) {
    if (name !== 'core/paragraph') {
        return settings;
    }

    return lodash.assign({}, settings, {
        attributes: lodash.assign({}, settings.attributes, {
            label: {
                type: 'string',
                default: ""
            }
        })
    });
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'core/paragraph',
    addLabelAttribute
);
```

**Part 2:** Create a [Higher Order Component](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-compose/) to insert the `<label>...<\label>` into `<BlockEdit>` only if a label is set. The value of the label attribute is destructured from the props:

plugin.js

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { useBlockProps } = wp.blockEditor;

const withLabelOutput = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {

    return (props) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();
        const { attributes: { label } } = props;

        if (label) {
            // Add the custom label within a wrapped <BlockEdit>
            return (
                <div {...blockProps}>
                    <label>{label}</label>
                    <BlockEdit {...props} />
                </div>
            );
        }
        // No label set, return default <BlockEdit>
        return (<BlockEdit {...props} />)
    };
}, 'withLabelOutput');

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'core/paragraph',
    withLabelOutput
);
```

Ref: [Block Editor Handbook > Block Filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/)

**Part 3:** Set a default value for the new label attribute within the template of the required post/custom post type:

plugin.php:

```
function myplugin_register_template(){
    // N.B. Use a custom post type unless you want this to apply to all posts
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object('post');
    $post_type_object->template = array(
        array(
            'core/paragraph',
            array(
                'placeholder' => 'Add Description...',
                'label' => 'My Custom Label'
            )
        )
    );
    $post_type_object->template_lock = 'all';
}

add_action('init', 'myplugin_register_template');
```

*(Optional)* Add a your own custom editor style for the `<label>`, and [enqueue it for the editor only](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/javascript/extending-the-block-editor/), eg:

```
.wp-block-paragraph label{
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

All the code example given above can be combined into a plugin, which creates a label in the Editor like:
[image: Editor Example with Paragraph Block]